# Asterisk ringgroup get call after registration

Tags: asterisk, sip, freepbx

I have 10 extensions grouped into RingGroup with number "100" and "ringall" strategy. Only 4 of 10 extensions online. Someone call to 100 and 4 online extensions gets call and starts ringing. So, how can I get this call if one (or more) of 6 offline extensions gets online (until call is active)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you should use queue for such functionality, ring group is not really good for such case, but there is a hack to achieve what you need even with ring group.

First make sure that destination if no answer is same group. then make sure that "Ring Time" is configured for quite low value like 10 seconds.

In this case when call hits ring group it will ring only 4 available extensions for 10 seconds, after 10 seconds it will go back to same group and it will ring all available extensions at that moment, so if 1 additional extensions will go online, then it will call 5 extensions for 10 seconds and etc.

Comment: I've tried queue, and there are too big lag between calls. Also, I with to keep call if client already ringing. I've try 10 seconds Ring Time with 0 seconds delay, but have 3-4 seconds real delay between recalls.

Comment: What you want to do is not really standard feature, so if you really need it, then probably you can write script which will listen for events from Asterisk Manager Interface and when extension will go online, then you may send call to that extension. Not sure that it will work, cause I tried once to do something similar, but there was bug/issue in core which didn't allow me to track properly when extension goes online and offline, but maybe they fixed this recently.

Comment: Thank you, i'll try to play with call forwarding and asterisk events today